# Is there a way to filter data from jinja2 with using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jinja2

Simply I have a data which coming from jinja2. I want to filter data when I clicked the button. Another solution might be to pass the data to a javascript variable.

I have created an example for more clear definition. In this case I want to delete numbers which are less then 5. Then I list them in html.

In template;

```
{% set data = [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] %}
     
<ul> 
  {% for item in data %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<button class="btn">Filter Data</button>
```

In Script

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
// filter here
}
```

Comment: its not clear what you want? i suppose you are working on the html code after the templating, so what do you want to filter by clicking on button???? i dont understant the result you are waiting

Comment: I have an array where I keep my blogs datas. Each blog has a category. I want the array to be filtered according to the categories  when I press the filter buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is that you also provide the data value as an attribute of the list item, e.g. `data-index`:

```
{% set data = [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] %}
     
<ul class="mylist"> 
  {% for item in data %}
    <li data-index="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<button class="btn">Filter Data</button>
```

Then you loop over the list items after the click event and based on the value of `el.dataset.index`, you can remove the respective items:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let items = document.querySelectorAll(".mylist li")
    Array.from(items, el => {
        if (el.dataset.index < 5) {
            el.remove()
            // Or: el.style.display = 'none'
        }
    })    
}
```